# Density for joint discrete continuous distribution

Tags: probability

I am trying to make sure I understand how to write the density for a joint discrete continuous distribution.

Suppose I want to modify an exponential($\lambda$) random variable $X$. An example is I measure how long it takes for an event to occur following an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$ but up to a maximum time $T$, after which I treat it as just occurring after $T$.

If I want to model $X$, the density is the same as Exp($\lambda$) when $X$ is less than some constant $T$. But if $X\geq T$, then I treat it as one value of Pr$(X\geq T) = e^{-T\lambda}$.

So my interpretation for the distribution for $X$ is

$$f(x)= (1-e^{-T\lambda})(\lambda e^{-x\lambda}) + (e^{-T\lambda})^2.$$

First we have two cases for whether $X<T$ with probability $1-e^{-T\lambda}$ or $X\geq T$ with probability $e^{-T\lambda}$. In the first case, the distribution is exponential so we multiply by $\lambda e^{-x\lambda}$. In the second case, the distribution is $e^{-T\lambda}$ which is just the probability of coming after $T$.

I am not sure if this interpretation and density function is correct and would like someone to check and/or point out any mistakes. It seems I am introducing expectation when it shouldn't appear.

EDIT: I realized that it is definitely wrong but I am not sure how to correct it in a way without introducing other random variables and where it would still be easy to work with, say, in a MLE.

Comment: You could use the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function to "encode" which part of the exponential density to "multiply away" (modify it to make it 0 where you want it to cut off the other function you multiply it with).

Comment: The heaviside function is a rather drastic one being all discontinous and stuff, you can smooth it if you want to make the transition from 1 to 0 less dramatic. ( It does have some implications in the Fourier domain for example ).